# django-haystack larger numbers returned as smaller

Tags: python, django, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Currently running django-haystack with elasticsearch. Currently when I try to order prices of product a larger number is seen as smaller in the list. E.g. 19,342 is smaller than 2345 because of the first two charactes. 1 and 9.

Anyone come across this before?

Comment: Because you are storing prices as string into your elastic search. Store it as float/int and change the type in Django model. it will work fine as expected

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've converted it to an integer in search_index.py and changed my model to an integer to test this and it still doesn't sort correctly. It's as if it's only looking at the first two digits.

EDIT: Yup sorry, my search_index had DecimalField rather than IntegerField, this is now fixed thanks. Must have put it back with all the testing back and forth. Thank you.